# How can I use DropZone without type="submit" button? And how can I do to intercept the file in .Net Core?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, .net-core

I dont know how to use DropZone without `type="submit"` button. I also don't know how to intercept the file in `.Net Core`. Can somebody help me? I know it seems to be difficult, but, please, help me. Thanks

Here is the `HTML` code:

```
<form role="form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <!-- TextEmail -->
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative">
            <div class="input-group-prepend d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-inline d-xl-inline">
                <span class="input-group-text "><strong><i class="fas fa-at"></i> TextEmail</strong></span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="testing-test-textemail-input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- TextFile -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative" style="height:135px;">
            <div class="input-group-prepend d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-inline d-xl-inline">
                <span class="input-group-text "><strong><i class="fas fa-file"></i> TextFile</strong></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <div id="testing-test-textfile-input" class="dropzone dropzone-single" data-toggle="dropzone" data-dropzone-defaultmessage="<i class='fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-3x'></i>" data-dropzone-url="http://">
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dz-preview dz-preview-single">
                        <div class="dz-preview-cover">
                            <img class="dz-preview-img" src="" alt="" data-dz-thumbnail>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="testing-test-textfile-file" name="file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <button id="testing-test-insert-or-update-button" class="btn btn-primary text-nowrap ml-3 mt-4" type="button">
            Edit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my `jQuery` code in `TypeScript`:

```
import { TestModel } from "../TsModels/Test_TsModel";
import * as $ from "jquery";
import Dropzone from "dropzone";

class TestNonQuery {
    static InsertOrUpdate(testModel: TestModel) {
        TestModel.Insert(testModel).subscribe({
            next: newrow => {
            },
            complete: () => {
            },
            error: err => {
            }
        });
    }
}

function ValidateAndInsertOrUpdate() {

    var _testmodel: TestModel = {
        TextEmail: $("#testing-test-textemail-input").val(),
        TextFile: $("#testing-test-textfile-file").val(),
    };

    TestNonQuery.InsertOrUpdate(_testmodel);
}

//LOAD EVENT
if ($("#testing-test-title-page").html().includes("Edit test")) {
    Dropzone.options.testing_test_form = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,

        init: function (e) {

            var myDropzone = this;

            $('#testing-test-insert-or-update-button').on("click", function () {
                myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
            });

            // Event to send your custom data to your server
            myDropzone.on("sending", function (file, xhr, data) {

                // First param is the variable name used server side
                // Second param is the value, you can add what you what
                // Here I added an input value
                data.append("your_variable", $('#your_input').val());
            });

        }
    };
}

//Button to add or update
$("#testing-test-insert-or-update-button").on("click", function (e) {
    ValidateAndInsertOrUpdate();
});
```

This is the `TypeScript` model to add in body of HTTP protocol, using `rxjs` library:

```
export class TestModel {

    //Fields
    TextEmail?: string | string[] | number | undefined;
    TextFile?: string | string[] | number | undefined;

    static Insert(TestModel: TestModel) {
        let URL = '/api/Testing/Test/1/Insert';
        let Body = {
            TextEmail: TestModel.TextEmail,
            TextFile: TestModel.TextFile,
        };
        let Header: any = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        };
        return Rx.from(ajax.post(URL, Body, Header));
    }

}
```

And this is the controller in `.Net Core`:

```
[HttpPost("~/api/Testing/Test/1/Insert")]
        public IActionResult Insert([FromBody] TestModel TestModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var SyncIO = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
                if (SyncIO != null) { SyncIO.AllowSynchronousIO = true; }

                int NewEnteredId = _TestProtocol.Insert(TestModel);
                return StatusCode(200, NewEnteredId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
            }
        }
```